# Error using vuelidate in quasar: "ReferenceError: process is not defined"

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework, vuelidate

I am building an application with the Quasar framework.
For form validation, I am using vuelidate for validation.

Quasar version:

» Pkg quasar........ v2.0.3

» Pkg @quasar/app... v3.0.3

Vuelidate:

"vuelidate": "^0.7.6"

"Similiar" code basically works with another quasar 1.X application, but fails with quasar 2.x:

Boot configuration:

```js
import Vuelidate from 'vuelidate';

export default ({ app }) => {
  app.use(Vuelidate);
};
```

Component:

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <q-input
      filled
      label="Tweets"
      type="text"
      v-model="$v.tweets.$model"
      :error="$v.tweets.$error"
      @blur="$v.tweets.$touch"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
import { required, numeric } from "vuelidate/lib/validators";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "StatsForm",
  data() {
    return {
      tweets: null,
    };
  },
  validations: {
    tweets: { required, numeric },
  },
});
</script>
```

The code where component is used:

```js
<template>
  <q-page class="flex justify-center q-ma-md">
    <div class="column">
      <h1>Twitter Profile Performance Report</h1>
      <stats-form />
    </div>
  </q-page>
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
import StatsForm from "../components/StatsForm.vue";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "PerformanceReport",
  components: {
    "stats-form": StatsForm,
  },
});
</script>

<style>
h1 {
  font-size: 2.5em;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1em;
}
</style>
```

I am getting this error in Browser:

```
vue-router.esm-bundler.js?f6c4:3248 ReferenceError: process is not defined
    at eval (withParams.js?8b99:7)
    at Object../node_modules/vuelidate/lib/withParams.js (vendor.f2dee45ef25904390a82.hot-update.js:271)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:195)
    at fn (app.js:460)
    at eval (common.js?bca9:14)
    at Object../node_modules/vuelidate/lib/validators/common.js (vendor.f2dee45ef25904390a82.hot-update.js:62)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:195)
    at fn (app.js:460)
    at eval (alpha.js?d360:8)
    at Object../node_modules/vuelidate/lib/validators/alpha.js (vendor.f2dee45ef25904390a82.hot-update.js:18)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vuelidate [v0.7.6](https://github.com/vuelidate/vuelidate/releases/tag/v0.7.6) is from Oct 23, 2020 and is compatible only with Vue 2. You are using Vue 3 which means you **have to** use [Vuelidate v2](https://github.com/vuelidate/vuelidate/tree/next)

Comment: I am using Vue 2 and still getting this error

Comment: The solution is not related to the problem

Comment: @AndresChica Well it was clear problem of original question and given the fact he marked the answer, probably it was solution to HIS problem. The fact that you can get similar (or same) error message in different circumstances does non make my answer bad...

Comment: You're right, bad calcification undoned